# Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps error when debug on IOs

Tags: google-maps, xamarin.forms

I have a big problem. I'm using Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps to use function in it.
When i debug app on Android, it work very good. But when i debug app on IOs, it appear bug. I found some solution to solve it, but cannot.
Someone can help me, plz?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRKxP.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6nVK.png)

Comment: share you code!

Comment: When i install Xamarin.Google.IOS.Maps and debug, it appear a bug. I have'nt edited code!